# Add a comma to the end of each line using php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, csv

I am having a csv file with 1 email id in each line. I want to add comma after each email id. I want to add a comma to the end of each line using php. How can i do this? Is there a particular function for that?

**UPDATE**
I want this so that I can construct an array out of it in javascript.

I will be loading the csv file using php and then printing it in my js.

Like

```
var myCars=[<?php print $csv; ?>];
```

So that I acheive something like this.

```
var myCars=["Saab@gmail.com","Volvo@gmail.com","BMW@gmail.com"];
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Adding commaa each line would no longer make it a valid CSV file ??? can you explain your use case

Comment: Files without commas are already valid CSVs. What is the true nature of the problem you're experiencing? Failure to parse?

Comment: its already a valid CSV .. you don't have to put a comma

Comment: I want to use it as an array in javascript. I think for that i will need the commas. I have updated the question.

Comment: Can you be clear? CSV, Javascript, PHP. You are mixing a lot of stuff vaguely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the csv-specific functions?

```
$old = fopen('file.csv','r');
$new = fopen('new.csv','w+');
while($line = fgetcsv($old))
{
    fputcsv($new,$line);
}
fclose($old);
fclose($new);
```

The above code will write a new csv, line per line, but if you just want to generate a javascript array, why not do this:

```
$file = fopen ('file.csv','r');
$all = array();
while($line = fgetcsv($file))
{
    $all[] = $line[0];//if there is only 1 field/line
    $all = array_merge($all,$line);//if multiple
}
fclose($file);
$js_array = '["'.implode('",',$all).'"];';
//or, the way I'd advise against, but good for multi-dimensional, assoc arrays
echo 'var array = JSON.parse("'.json_encode($all).'");';
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$lines = file('file.csv');
foreach ( $lines as & $line ) {
    $line .= ',';
}
file_put_contents('file.new.csv', implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
```

something like that should do, 
cheers

Comment: Currently the comma is coming in new line. :/ Is there any way it comes end of each email id?

Comment: correct, my fault, should add a trim(): $line = trim($line).','; instead of $line .= ',';

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$lines = file('org.csv');
foreach ( $lines as & $line ) {
    $line = trim( $line ) . ',';
}
file_put_contents('new.csv', implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
```

Comment: after reading your last update, i would say to add this for the JS, you need to remove the last trailing comma from the last line else the array will break in JS: var myCars=[<?php echo trim(file_get_contents('file.csv'), ','); ?>];

Answer (score 2):

why not just

```
$csv = str_replace("\n", ",\n", $csv);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of echoing an entire csv string, you can import the file to an array using the fgetcsv function, then echo it out using json_encode().  That way you're sure to get a valid javascript array.  It will also quote and encode any strings for you.

Oh, remember to run the array through some iterator which will run utf8_encode on all strings.  If you have invalid utf8 characters, json_encode will barf.

There are plenty of examples on php.net of doing the different parts of this, but I can provide some examples if needed.